# Using last row value in another set of formula

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have 3 columns, (AB,AC & AD) . I need to sum Column AB & AC to its last Row as data varies as to number of rows. In column AD, I need to divide the amount of every cell, lets say AB1 to the sum of column AB and then divide it by the sum of column AD, in which sum of both are placed in the last Row of each column.

I already have the formula, however, my problem is after running the macro, in the formula bar, the sum of both AB & AC are hard-coded numbers. it shows like =AB1/200*300 , what i need is to show the cell reference like this =AB1/AB30*AC30 (provided last row is in row30), since sum of both columns may change if i need to add new rows in between or in cases where amount on those cells will be changed.

My current formula is this:

```
LastRow = Range("AB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Range("AB" & LastRow & ":AC" & LastRow).Formula = "=Sum(AB2:AB" & LastRow - 1 & ")"

Range("AD2:AD" & LastRow - 1).Formula = "=AB2/" & Range("AB" & LastRow) & "*" & Range("AC" & LastRow).Value
```

Please help. Thank you!

Regards,
Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `.Value` return the `Address(0,0)`

```
Range("AD2:AD" & LastRow - 1).Formula = "=AB2/" & Range("AB" & LastRow).Address(1,1) & "*" & Range("AC" & LastRow).Address(1,1)
```

But there is no reason to do that either as you can just concatenate the last row value in:

```
Range("AD2:AD" & LastRow - 1).Formula = "=AB2/AB$" & LastRow & "*" & "AC$" & LastRow
```

Comment: Hi Scot, thank you for that! this actually works and it gives me the cell reference of the last row. However, it only works perfectly in cell AD2, all other cells below it provides the incorrect last row . eg. last row is AB30 , in AD2 to it is correctly =AB2/AB30*AC30. however in AD3 it shows =AB3/AB31*AC31 , using cell 31 instead of 30. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks Scott!

Comment: Hi Scott, I already have it figured out, I just changed the Address.(0,0) to Adress (True, True) instead. Thank you!